# mallet doesnt work even for help command

Tags: mallet

I am gonna use mallet fir topic modelling and I am using linux.
I have installed mallet (but not ant)and I have java in my system.So when I want to use commands for mallet it doesnt work.The only command that works is : bin/mallet
which gives me a list of commands.but if I type :
bin/mallet import-dir --help
It gives me this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/Interpreter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption.<init>(CommandOption.java:62)
    at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption$SpacedStrings.<init>(CommandOption.java:552)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.<clinit>(Text2Vectors.java:30)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 14 more
Could not find the main class: cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors. Program will exit.
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you set the environment variable 'MALLET_HOME'?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you said you typed `bin/mallet import-dir --help`. It is an executable file so you should have typed `./bin/mallet import-dir --help`. If it was a typo then please ignore this part.

Also, I had the same issue with mallet 2.0.8RC2. It threw an exception for all commands, even for --help. I downloaded mallet-2.0.7 and built it using ant again. Now it works.

Also, try downloading the tool again.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are missing bsh.jar. Usually the MALLET package have a full set of jar files and bsh.jar should be one of them in the .\mallet-2.0.7\lib directory.

If you cannot find it there, you can either download the package from the MALLET site again or google it. But the version of the jar file is important, make sure you are using the right version.

Comment: Please do not tell us "google it". This site is supposed to provide self-contained information!